# Rails 3 Routes and model setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Just looking to know what the best practice is to do the following.

I have two models

```
Group
  id    int pk
  name  string

Company
  id   int pk
  name string
```

A group instance can have zero or many instances of companies

A company instance can have zero or many instances of groups

Validate that a company cannot belong to the same group more than once

use a has_and_belongs_to_many association (No intervening model) ?

use a has_many :through (setup an organisation model) ?

I want to setup restful views to:

```
Group
/groups     (Show All Group Names)
/groups/1   (Show one group)
/groups/new (Add Group)
etc...


Companies
/companies/1 (show all companies)
/companies/1 (Show company)
/companies/new (Add Company)
etc...
```

The issue i am trying to get around is how do I setup the following views with the models ?

```
(Show all companies for a specified group) /groups/1/companies ??
(Add, update and remove companies for a specified group ?!)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [nested routes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources?view=comments)

e.g. write in your `routes.rb` file

```
  resources :groups do 
    resources :companies
  end
```

then in your model a company belongs_to a group and a group has_many companies.

make sure to check out the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for more information on routing.

Comment: A company doesn't necessarily belong to a group as mentioned above (A company instance can have zero or many instances of groups). A company can exist without being part of a group...

Comment: you can add resource :companies twice, once normal and once nested under groups in your routes file. the nesting is necessary if you want routes like "/groups/1/companies". type "rake routes" on the console to get detailed information about your app's routings

Comment: Ahh i see... if i duplicate the resources whats the best way to setup the controllers models ?? thanks

Comment: Would I need to setup a third model (for example corporation) using the has_many :through association and use resources :corporation to show all companies within a group, add, remove, update etc... ?

Comment: The nested route is just a different route to get to the same controller. So `/groups/1/companies` would list all companies for group with id=1, and `/companies` would just list all companies. But both arrive at the same controller, the same action. Only the nested route will have an extra parameter `group_id=1`. HTH.

Comment: The penny has dropped! lol... That makes total sense now.. Can i make separate views for the nested resources under the views folder?

Comment: you would not use different view, you would probaly render a partial if a condition is given, like "if @company.group.exist? render 'group'" or something similar

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, still trying to get my head around rails and how to map things out into resources, controllers and models